# Time field is coming up blank in Active Admin with sqlite3 database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activeadmin

I'm working with a local database on sqlite3 with Rails 3.2.3 and Active Admin. Two of my fields are of the type, time which I know is not a type in sqlite3 but we're using postgres for production (not my choice to do not do them both in postgres). In the new/edit form, I put:

```
  f.input :time_start, :as => :time_select
  f.input :time_end, :as => :time_select
```

It shows as a field (as it does without the time_select) but when I enter numbers and try to save it, the field ends up blank on the next page. I pushed it to staging using heroku and postgres and it's still ending up blank when I try to edit activities. How would I be able to create and save that time field on the local and staging databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after renaming time_start and time_end, it worked. Then it stopped working. So I changed them to datetime sand now it works although the date fields are useless.

Answer (score 1):

Just faced the same problem. Guess this is some kind of ActiveAdmin bug.

My temporary way out is to change t.time with 2 corresponding t.integer's and make something like

```
f.inputs "Start" do
  f.input :time_start_h, as: :select, collection: 0..23
  f.input :time_start_m, as: :select, collection: 0..59
end
f.inputs "End" do
  f.input :time_end_h, as: :select, collection: 0..23
  f.input :time_end_m, as: :select, collection: 0..59
end
```

Rough, but better than nothing.

Comment: Yeah apparently renaming it works. I didn't mark this as correct because it separates hours and minutes which I didn't want to do but that does work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I get around this issue by setting my time fields as strings:

```
f.inputs "Start" do
  f.input :start, :as => :string
end
```

This allows for inputs like "2pm" which I find actually preferable to the drop downs.